# Id of object not saving

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to update the listing_id of Photo but for some reason it won't save the id. I'm passing in an array of 3 or more image id's and then iterating over each one here is the code:

```
 def create
    @listing.landlord = current_landlord
    if @listing.save
      params[:listing][:images].each do |image|
        Photo.find_by_id(image).listing_id = @listing.id
        @listing.save
      end
      render :show, :status => 200
    else
      render :status => 403, :json => {:errors => @listing.errors}
    end
  end
```

Any ideas to way the Photo isn't saving the Listing id?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Photo.find_by_id(image).listing_id = @listing.id
@listing.save
```

Why do you call `@listing.save` ehen you want to save a photo? Also, you're setting `listing_id` on a temp variable that won't be able to access. You probably meant to write something like this

```
photo = Photo.find_by_id(image)
photo.listing_id = @listing.id
photo.save
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call save on photo object instead of listing,

instead of this code

```
  Photo.find_by_id(image).listing_id = @listing.id
  @listing.save
```

try

```
 photo=  Photo.find_by_id(image)
 photo.listing_id = @listing.id
 photo.save
```